# Insert same text multiple times on one line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often have to insert sequences like

```
:1, :2, :3, :4, :5
```

into a plain text file. That's easy to do with 5 items like in my example but it becomes tedious if I have something like 42 items. Is there a possibility that I only type the colon and have it repeated a number of times on the same line?

I can do the numbering using [an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomoki1207.vscode-input-sequence) so it would be nice if multiple cursors would be placed after the inserted colons immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Is there a way to insert N times the same characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149126/is-there-a-way-to-insert-n-times-the-same-characters/63158335#63158335) for some options on inserting repeated text.

Using the [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips) approach this snippet in your `plaintext.hsnips` file will do what you want:

```
snippet `:\*(\d+)=` "expand" A
``
let howMany = parseInt(m[1]);
let start = 1;
let newStr = '';
for (let index = 0; index < howMany; index++) {
    newStr += `:${start++}, `;
}
rv=`${newStr.slice(0,-2)}`
``
endsnippet
```

[image: demo of repeating snippet]

Since it is just javascript, you can make that snippet as generic as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen). You write a Regular Expression that generates your needed text

Type the following in the Generate Box

```
(:{{=j[0]+1}}, ){10}
```

You are left with the `,`  at the end

To place the multiple cursors:

1. Select the generated text
2. Open the find dialog: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
3. Enable `Find in Selection`: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
4. Search for `:`
5. Add cursors on all selections: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Move cursor after selection: <kbd>ArrowRight</kbd>