# How to set the insertion of automatic space after a colon in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to set that if I write a colon, I am automatically added a space after it. I used to use IntelliJ IDEA, which did this automatically when working with JSON. Can this be set in VSC as well?

Comment: what if you add a keybinding to `:` to `type` `: ` (colon space)

Comment: I edited file  keybindings.json like: 
{
  "key": ":",
  "command": "type",
  "args": {
    "text": ": "
  }
} 
but, not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips) is one way to do it.

In your json.hsnips file (so it is limited to `json` files):

```
snippet `:` "expand to : " A
``rv = ': '``
endsnippet
```

Now whenever you type a `:` it will be expanded to `:`  in a `json` file.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62562886/836330 for more info.

---

Just using `:` as a key to a prefix in a keybinding won't work as you must have a modifier key - like <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, etc.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_accepted-keys.

You could do something like:

```
{ 
  "key": "alt+;",      // I chose ; because it is on the same key for me as :
  "command": "type", 
  "args": { "text": ": " },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == json"
},
```

and that would work.