# Can I include conditional logic in VS Code snippets?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I would like to write a snippet in VS Code that writes a "switch" expression (in Javascript), but one where I can define the number of cases.

Currently there is a snippet that produces the outline of a switch expression with 1 case, and allows you to tab into the condition, case name, and the code contained within.

I want to be able to type *"switch5"* (*"5"* being any number) and a switch with 5 cases to be created, where I can tab through the relevant code within.

I know the snippets are written in a JSON file, can I include such conditional logic in this, or is it not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot do that kind of thing in a standard vscode snippet because it cannot dynamically evaluate any input outside of its designated variables with some limited workarounds like I'll mention next.

You might - I and others have written answers on SO about his - type your various `case` values first and then trigger a snippet tat would transform them into a `switch` statement.  It is sort of doing it backwords but it might be possible.

There are extensions, however, that do allow you to evaluate javascript right in a snippet or setting and output the result.  [macro-commander](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeff-hykin.macro-commander) is one such extension.  I'll show another simpler extension doing what you want: [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips).

In your `javascript.hsnips`:

```
snippet `switch(\d)` "add number of cases to a switch statement" A
``
let numCases = Number(m[1])     // 'm' is an array of regex capture groups
let caseString = ''

if (numCases) {       // if not 'switch0'
    let tabStopNum = 1
    caseString = `switch (\${${tabStopNum++}:key}) {\n`

    for (let index = 0; index < m[1]; index++) {
        caseString += `\tcase \${${tabStopNum++}:value}:\n\t\t\$${tabStopNum++}\n`
        caseString += '\t\tbreak;\n\n'
    }

    caseString += '\tdefault:\n'
    caseString += '\t\tbreak;\n}\n'
}
rv = `${caseString}`       // return value
``
endsnippet
```

[image: switch HyperSnips demo]

---

The trickiest part was getting the unknown number of tabstops to work correctly.  This is how I did it:

```
\${${tabStopNum++}:key}
```

which will resolve to `${n:defaultValue}` where `n` gets incremented every time a tabstop is inserted.  And  `:defaultValue` is an optional default value to that tabstop.  If you don't need a defaultValue just use `\$${tabStopNum++}` there.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62562886/836330 for more info on how to set up HyperSnips.

Comment: I forgot to note that it works for 0-9 cases at the moment, not beyond.  If necessary that may be fixable in the regex prefix `switch(\d)`.