# How to execute snippet instantaneously - vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

Is there the option to "execute snippets" right away in vscode, meaning without having to press tab? This is really the only thing holding me back from vscode because in vim I can simply configure it, so e.g. if I have a snippet which gets triggered if I type `test` it automatically replaces `test` by the snippet content without having to press any extra key like tab. Is this possible in vscode?

Comment: See the extension `HyperSnips`.

Comment: @Mark wow this seems very similar to UltiSnips, interesting!

Comment: I'm sure it is a "port" of some sort.  If you search for HyperSnips here on SO, you will see a few questions that I and others answered that should help you.  Particularly https://stackoverflow.com/a/62562886/836330 although that is sort of a complicated example.

Comment: Oh thanks, but somehow I can now expand snippets instantly, when I don't add any additional flags they won't expand when pressing tab. Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: No, I have seen the exact same thing with that extension.     Someone should file an issue on it.