# How to use Hypersnips?

Tags: reactjs, regex, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

I have been trying to use a custom snippet using hypersnips, but it doesn't seem to work. I have installed the extension in vs code and wrote the snippet in all.hsnips, but I am not able to use it inside my react file. Can someone help me with this?
This is my snippet code(all.hsnips)

```
snippet `divx\.([^ ]+) ` "expand to jsx className" A
<div className={``rv=m[1]``}>$1</div>
endsnippet
```

I have also referred these
[LaTeX fraction snippets in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545965/latex-fraction-snippets-in-vscode/62562886#62562886)

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me in an `all.hsnips` file.  Did you `HyperSnips: Reload Snippets` from the Command Palette after making any changes to the `all.snips` file?  [For performance reasons probably better to put the snippet into `javascriptreact.hsnips` instead.]

Comment: Yes I added the snippet in all.hsnips, then did HyperSnips: Reload Snippets in vs code. Then I opened my react file and then isn't it supposed to automatically activate? Or is there any other step that I missed?

Comment: No other steps.  Your regex prefix does have a space at the end so it won't trigger until that space, so something like `divx.myClassName ` should trigger it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have got it working. I forgot that space triggers it..